# Can this unreadable terraform code-snippet be made more presentable?

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, hcl

I have a code snippet that sets the node pool name for a GKE cluster, it is very much unreadable. I would appreciate any help in making it more presentable and easy to understand what is happening.

```
output "test" {
  value = regex("(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,38}[a-z0-9])?)", lower(var.node_pool_version != "" ? var.node_pool_name != "" ? "${var.node_pool_name}-v${replace("${var.node_pool_version}",".","-")}" : "${var.name_prefix}-v${replace("${var.node_pool_version}",".","-")}" : var.node_pool_name != "" ? var.node_pool_name : "${var.name_prefix}-standard"))
}

variable "node_pool_version" {
  description = "Override node_version for cluster upgrades"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "node_pool_name" {
  type    = string
  default = ""
}

variable "name_prefix" {
  type    = string
  default = "develop"
}
```

Outputs:

```
❯ terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

test = develop-standard
❯ terraform apply -var node_pool_version=1.16.15-gke.7800

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

test = develop-v1-16-15-gke-7800
❯ terraform apply -var node_pool_version=1.16.15-gke.7800 -var node_pool_name=develop-standard

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.

Outputs:

test = develop-standard-v1-16-15-gke-7800
```

Edit:
My concern is with the extensive usage of `String Functions` & `Conditional Expressions` to generate the output. My use-case is if the user doesn't pass either `node_pool_version` or `node_pool_name`, my output should still manage to generate a node-name that can be easily identifiable. Is there a better way to re-write this code and make it more readable for anyone new to Terraform?

Comment: you could do multiple outputs, can't you?

Comment: Added some more clarity of what I am looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose the best you could do is use a [locals](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/locals.html) block:

```
variable "node_pool_version" {
  description = "Override node_version for cluster upgrades"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

variable "node_pool_name" {
  type    = string
  default = ""
}

variable "name_prefix" {
  type    = string
  default = "develop"
}

locals {
  version            = replace("${var.node_pool_version}", ".", "-")
  prefix             = var.node_pool_name != "" ? var.node_pool_name : var.name_prefix
  id                 = var.node_pool_name != "" ? local.prefix : "${local.prefix}-standard"
  versioned_id       = local.version != "" ? "${local.prefix}-v${local.version}" : local.id
  clean_versioned_id = regex("(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,38}[a-z0-9])?)", lower(local.versioned_id))
}

output "test" {
  value = local.clean_versioned_id
}
```